# Jupyter installed and yet can't run Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, jupyter-notebook

Having installed Jupyter using `pip install jupyter` I am getting the following error messages.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\J>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 32, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    _libsodium = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled_sodium[0])
  File "c:\python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

C:\Users\J>python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

C:\Users\J>
```

However I do have Jupyter installed

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\J>python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jupyter
>>>
```

The last time I used Windows it was XP so I am getting used to all the changes (or never got used to it at

Comment: apparently I was missing C++ [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

Comment: When in Windows, you might be interested in using [Conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html). ;-)